# Given three divs aligned horizontally, how can I make the center div clear the other two in the event that the browser window resizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

To go into more detail, consider this:

- I have a row of three divs **R**(right), **C**(center), and **L**(left).
- They are encapsulated within a parent div **Container**
- **Container** has the css style **display:inline-block**
- I have **L** floated left
- I have **R** floated right.
- I have **C** centered by setting **margin: auto**.

**My problem**: 
 I want the middle div to be centered until **R** and **L** collide with it. In the event that this happens (window resize). I want **C** to clear both, and center itself underneath **R**.

What is the best way to achieve such a result? I understand I may have approached the set up wrong, please advise if that is the case!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked into media queries?

Comment: Yeah I have, but I was trying to avoid adding an additional media query if possible

Comment: Do you have an example fiddle or any code you've been trying out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @atdrago mentioned, media queries is really the way to go here.

If your widths are fixed, you can also try floating the center div to the left and putting a (fixed) `max-width` on the `.container` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrhps/2/ is a working example.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll look into another media query then. I appreciate the fiddle too !

Answer (score 0):

Would have commented, but not enough reputation. Anyway, you will need a listener for resize -  it will be nasty. Media Query is the way to go as mentioned.

[is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/S74Fh/2/)

```
.C {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
    @media (max-width: 20em) {
        clear: left;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Sorry new here, it appears I need add code from the jfiddle to post a link...oO